# How to require a specific file of a project using Composer?

Tags: php, json, requirejs, composer-php

I have a `composer.json` file like this one:

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "*",
        "ajbdev/requirejs": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

But I'd like get just the `ajbdev/requirejs/require.js` file. How can I do this with Composer?

*Edit:*

As @dev-null-dweller proposed, the following worked to me, but is it the best solution?

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": "rm -rf vendor/ajbdev && mkdir vendor/ajbdev && mkdir vendor/ajbdev/requirejs && wget -q --no-check-certificate -O vendor/ajbdev/requirejs/require.js https://raw.github.com/ajbdev/requirejs/master/require.js"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scripting hook](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) and get this file by providing full URL to it, ie:

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": "wget -q -P vendor/file/output/dir/ --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/ajbdev/requirejs/master/require.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, works. Almost there. Now, how can I tell composer to put this file at the folder `ajbdev/requirejs`? In this way the file is created at the `composher.phar` home folder.

Comment: This is shell scripting, so you can do what you want without depending on composer. If you are not familiar with shell, you can also write your code for it in php, just like last example on linked composer documentation.

Comment: I'd put the entire json file on my question. Thx.

Comment: @GarouDan Just in case you may find this useful, I had the same question as you but really didn't want to have to write a php script or use bash just to move a file around. Luckily, `wget` has a -P option to specify the output directory as you wish :)

Comment: @GarouDan Cool, don't forget to add the output dir of the `post-autoload-dump` to your `.gitignore` file - so others don't download the dependency with your application, and they can just use composer to do it.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT*

- Fork the package on github,
- Remove all files but the ones you'd like to have in your project and the package composer.json.
- Add your fork as a custom repository:

  ```
  {
      "repositories": [
           {
               "type":"vcs",
               "url":"git@github.com:Shalkydri/requirejs.git"
           }
      ],
      "require": {
           "components/jquery": "*",
           "ajbdev/requirejs": "dev-master"
      }
  }
  ```

*EDIT*

To only obtain the quoted "require.js" file you might locate the corresponding github package from packagist (https://packagist.org/packages/ajbdev/requirejs) before locating the file and its raw version on github :

https://github.com/ajbdev/requirejs/blob/master/require.js
https://raw.github.com/ajbdev/requirejs/master/require.js

*Original Answer*

You can execute the following command before providing any version constraint such as "dev-master"

```
php composer.phar require ajbdev/requirejs
```

Comment: Interesting, but can you help me the entire composer.json file with your solution? I'm not undestanding how to do this. Need I change `"ajbdev/requirejs": "dev-master"` to `"ajbdev/requirejs": ""`?

Comment: I tried execute your code, but composer still ask for a version. But how could this help me to get just the `require.js` file?

Comment: You might just need to answer dev-master when composer asks for a version. You will get more than just the require.js file but wouldn't it be enough to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm correcting using the requirejs (with all files), but I think the other files isn't needed, so, I'd like get just the needed files (at this case `require.js` file).